# How to create a ad hoc network on a router?

Tags: wireless-networking, ad-hoc-network

I want to create a LAN environment on my router without internet. I want to create an ad hoc network because I can see some performance benefit in this kind of network. Or is the Windows hosted network better in this scenario? PCs are at 100m range.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do this with more than a couple of computers certainly requires some kind of dedicated network rather than stringing the computers together directly.

100m is too far for low cost Wi-Fi equipment so you need a wired network. you don't however need a router for this, you can do it with a single switch if you have control over the wiring and position of the switch. If there are constraints, you might need to use more than one switch.

Of course, if you already have a router then it is likely that it has a 4-port switch built in that may well be sufficient. At 100m though, I'd bet that your cheap home router may not have what it takes to keep a reliable network connection.

Again, 100m is a long run of cable. Note that, over this distance, you need to start being careful about electrical charge differences between different parts of buildings. In particular, it can be dangerous to string wiring between buildings without understanding what you are doing. Get an expert in that case.